how to efficiently DESCRIBE thousands of tables from hive_metastore
We want to collect all kinds of information from the tables in the hive_metastore to generate metrics for future optimizations.
The hive_metastore contains hundreds of schemas and a total of ~150K tables.
Is there an efficient/parallelizable way to e.g. run a spark.sql("SHOW TABLES in {schema}).collect() for every schema and then run commands like spark.sql("DESCRIBE EXTENDED {table_name}").collect() for each table?
The question is intended preferably for usage with PySpark, but in case nothing is possible with the Python API, then we can use Scala.
Let me know if this is enough information on the case.
Thanks a lot in advance!

Below code is in scala You can convert it into pytho.
Increase or decrease numThreads depending on size of cluster.
import scala.collection.parallel.ForkJoinTaskSupport
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool
import org.apache.spark.sql._

val numThreads = 100 // Number of threads to execute query in parallel.
val schema = "" // Schema name
val showTables = s"SHOW TABLES FROM ${schema}"

val tableList = spark
    .sql(showTables)
    .selectExpr("CONCAT_WS('.', namespace, tableName) AS table")
    .distinct
    .as[String]
    .collect

val tableListPar = tableList.par
val taskSupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new ForkJoinPool(numThreads))
tableListPar.tasksupport = taskSupport

def describe(table: String): DataFrame = {
    val desc = s"DESCRIBE EXTENDED ${table}"
    println(s"Executing -> `${desc}`")
    spark.sql(desc)
    .withColumn("table", lit(table))
    .select(
        $"table", 
        $"col_name",
        $"data_type",
        $"comment"
    )
}

display(
  tableListPar.map(describe)
  .reduce(_.union(_))        
)

Please check similar questions answered here
